# How to make a non-primary column unique in a returned result-set with Laravel's eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

In this example below I am requesting all colleges where the state is CO. But I'd like to say `groupBy('name')` or *something* in order to get a single college name record.

I get the following error when I attempt:

```
# Error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'imr.colleges.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `colleges` where `state` = CO group by `name` limit 15 offset 135)

# Code:
College::where('state',$state)->groupBy('name')->paginate(15);
```

I don't particularly care which college (id) is returned, I just want to be able to return one of each college name per state.

Any assistance is appreciated.

[image: Collection of states returned]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
College::selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(id), name, GROUP_CONCAT(state)')->where('state',$state)->groupBy('name')->paginate(15);
```

Comment: I have updated the answer to concat the city column too. Please try again. Or you could totally omit the city from the query as you only need the name of the college!